# Notify when changes are made to infrastructure that was created by terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, infrastructure-as-code

I have created an infrastructure in AWS using terraform. I need to get a notification ,if changes are made to infrastructure through the AWS console that was created by terraform.

Is there any possible way to achieve the above use case

Comment: @Marcin, so there is no way to get notified if some resources which was created using terraform  is updated/changed through the console and not by using terraform . We will only know while we plan/apply right?

Comment: Just don't give users access to the console (or privileges) to create/change any resources.

Comment: yeah thats fine , but sometimes for the urgent use case , some will be changing it manually in the console . So I need to be notified if something is changed not using terraform

Comment: To prevent not being changed manually , and to know if something is changed manually without using terraform , I was searching for a solution

Comment: @MarkoE,Not changing every time manually, Some devs are changing it manually for quick fix . So the solution is no ? right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform Cloud has a [Drift Detection](https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/workspaces/health#drift-detection) feature which will periodically compare the results of the most recent Terraform run with the current state of remote objects and send notifications if it detects differences.

If you wish to implement something similar yourself outside of Terraform Cloud, one way to achieve it is to periodically run the following two steps:

- `terraform plan -refresh-only -out=tfplan`
- `terraform show -json tfplan`

The first command generates a "refresh-only plan", which only considers differences between the previous run result and the current object state, without also comparing with the current configuration.

The second command converts that plan into [a machine-readable JSON format](https://www.terraform.io/internals/json-format#plan-representation) which you can then interrogate with your own software to determine if there are any changes that you consider to be worthy of notifying about. The `resource_drift` property in that JSON format is the one most relevant to your goals here.

Comment: Yeah got it , searched resource_drift and I can see before and after properties in it. Is there any way to automate these commands on every 15 mins or an hour like that

Comment: If you are not using Terraform Cloud then any automatic runs of Terraform are outside of Terraform's scope and something you'll need to implement using a wrapping automation program. There are lots of different answers to that and I can't recommend any in particular since I don't know what else is in your environment, but some examples would be either using just a "cron job" (scheduled task) on a computer you already have running or, if you want more UI around it, a runbook automation tool like [Rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/).

Comment: If you _are_ using Terraform Cloud's feature then Terraform Cloud itself will periodically run assessments like this, without any special configuration on your part other than activating the feature.

Comment: Am using AWS . I wrote a build spec file , but while running terraform plan command , Its failing like assume role cannot be assumed . While doing a terraform init , I passed my credentials using -backend-config argument and initialized sucessfully, but there is no argument like -backend-config in terraform plan. How to solve this ?

Comment: This seems like it's becoming a new question now and so might be better to ask that way so you can include code examples for what you're trying already. However, the short answer is that Terraform remembers everything you pass to `terraform init -backend-config` in the working directory, so a subsequent `terraform plan` will use the same settings.